# Google sheets: Count unique values in Column B according to unique values in Column A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a big table with repeating dates in Column A and some repeating names in Column B. I need to count how many A there are in each month if we count one A for one date. So if there are two A's for 01.06.2021, so it will be counted as 1. The list of A, B, C contains about 20 names.

[image]

Comment: There are many ways to solve this, please share a sheet.

Comment: You are going to have problems if you only account for month and not also year. That is, once a new calendar year arrives, unless you account for it from the start, June 2021 and June 2022 will both just be seen as "June" and lumped together. Also, please indicate whether or not you will need the counts in the generated report to function as real numbers (e.g., able to be compared, added, etc.) or whether they can be strings (i.e., if you just need to SEE them and not DO anything further with them). I agree with JohnA, that sharing a sheet will be the most efficient means of getting help here.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(""&QUERY(UNIQUE({A:B\ TEXT(A:A; "mm\×mmmm yyyy")}); 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3"); 
 "(^\d+×)"; ))
```

[image]

---

or if you need numeric numbers:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(UNIQUE({A:B\ TEXT(A:A; "mm\×mmmm")}); 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3"); 
 "(^\d+×)"; ); QUERY(UNIQUE({A:B\ TEXT(A:A; "mm\×mmmm")}); 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col3")))
```

[image]

Comment: @JohnA, Thank you for your answers.  Here is the sheet: [link] https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NdSCaTS0E_weaOgQTlEGMrKhYdCyR7_QsUYqgTkE0LE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thank you for your formula @player0. I put it in the example sheet but it gives a mistake about the REGEXREPLACE. Could you please take a look?

Comment: @Erik Tyler. We can also use a year if it is easier to solve this problem. The reason why I mentioned only the month is that this sheet will operate only in one year. There will be a new one for the next year. I will need the counts to be real numbers, because there will be other calculations basing on them.